# vscode python linux: how to automatically open terminal in right venv?

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio-code

every time I open a vscode workspace I get a terminal the isn't attached to the right venv, although I did put the right python path in `ws.code-workspace.json`:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "python.pythonPath": ".venv/bin/python3"
    }
}
```

is there a way to automatically get the terminal running in the right venv?

Comment: Why not just add the line `"python.pythonPath": ".venv/bin/python3"` to your (workspace-)settings.json? If you then open a terminal it will automatically activate the virtual environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your steps to detect the venv path are correct, but:
The right answer is that currently the terminal isn't capable to auto open with the right venv- only the second opened terminal will detect the venv and open it automatically.

**UPDATE**: there is a new flag that one can use: `"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true`

Answer (score 5):

The latest setting is `"python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true`

Comment: This was all I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a virtual Python environment within VSCode you need to specify the *absolute path* to the corresponding interpreter.

Just add the following line to your workspace settings:

```json
"python.pythonPath": "absolute/path/to/venv/bin/python"
```

Now open a Python file and click on **Terminal** -> **New Terminal** and VSCode will automatically activate the virtual env as soon as the terminal launched.

As you see in the screenshot below, when opening a terminal the command

```
$ source /.../bin/activate
```

is executed automatically.

[image]

> **Note**: Before opening a new terminal there ***must*** be a Python file already ***open and focused*** to make VSCode activate the virtual env specified in workspace-settings. If instead you have a file focused which is not `.py` (for example a `.json` file), it will just open a new default terminal.

Comment: Bingo. The *note* part did it, thanks. [Vscode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) were not that clear on this matter.

Comment: Yeah nice one buddy, I have a mix of JS and Python in my service, making sure a python file was open did it!